# Passing parameter between two xhtml pages

Tags: jsf

I am trying to pass parameter between two pages .my User.xhtml page has two commandButon which authentified user .I have access to the user login. I want to click a button submit  and go to anthor page with the value of login .
Please help, I am pretty new in JSF

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using `f:param`

```
<h:commandButton action="#{userBean.action}">
       <f:param name="someparam" value="somevalue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

You can read more, and find other alternatives, about parameter passing in JSF at the following link: 
[Parameter Passing / Request Parameters in JSF 2.0](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com.es/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html)